# How to custom sort tags using org-tags-sort-function with org-set-tags

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to use C-c C-q to set tags from within the org capture templates buffer, and have the `:event:` tag (**if** it is used) always appear first in time (i.e., to the left of any other tags).  I set up an org capture template for events that inserts the initial tag of `:event:`.  However, `org-set-tags` defaults to `prepend` new tags to the beginning of the list instead of `append` them to the end of the tag list.

I see an option within the source code of `org-set-tags` for using a custom `org-tags-sort-function`, but I was not able locate any examples from which to copy / modify.  Does anyone have a sample of how to use `org-tags-sort-function` with `org-set-tags` so that something like the tag `:event:` could be automatically sorted first (i.e., to the left of all other tags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sort function is just a function comparing elements two at a time. There are two functions pre-defined in `org.el` in the `defcustom` of `org-tags-sort-function`:

```
(const :tag "Alphabetical" string<)
(const :tag "Reverse alphabetical" string>)
```

To build your custom sort function you can do the following:

```
(defun event-first (x y)
  (if (string= "event" x)
      t
    (if (string= "event" y)
      nil
      (string< x y))))
```

I chose, arbitrarily, to sort the non-"event" tags alphabetically but you can change that.